# Common session among few websites on different domains

Tags: web-services, cookies, authorization

I want to make few webservices, all of them will require login/pass authorization. I want to keep them all sync (one login, one password to all services), but also I want to share session between them.

If user is log in to service A, and open service B its automatically log in to this same account on service B like in service A.

How this is usually implemented?

Comment: What webserver are you using this with?

Comment: Can this be accomplished with ISA/IIS?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a database to support the sessions.

You could have a database record that holds key session information. If the database supports BLOB fields you could even hold more complex session data.

The record would have a "cookie thing" that the web service requests would present, the service implementation code would take that "cookie thing" and look in the database table(s) to see if a login event had correctly occurred recently.

(I say "cookie thing" because if it is a webservice it may not actually be a browser coming in).

Answer (score 1):

This is called a distributed session, implementations vary per webserver.

For Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

For WebSphere: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc%2Finfo%2Fiseriesnd%2Fae%2Fcprs_persistent_sessions.html

You can also store persisted variable in a database, which may be easier in your case.